# How to change default sort for Members in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

By default the Member object has the following sort:

```
private static $default_sort = '"Surname", "FirstName"';
```

We've got a project where I want to sort all the Members in the Security section of the CMS by "LastEdited DESC".

I've tried applying it using a DataExtension:

```
class ClubMemberFields extends DataExtension {

  private static $default_sort = 'LastEdited DESC'; 

...
}
```

YML:

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - 'ClubMemberFields'
```

Even after a /dev/build/ the Members are still being sorted by Surname/Firstname. What do I need to do to set the $default_sort to LastEdited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of silverstripe 3, there is a new config system in place.
this new config system also handles things like $db and $default_sort and so on.

you already use this config system in 2 ways, the usage of `private static $default_sort`, and the yml config files.

what many people don't know, is that those are one and the same config system.
So you can set `default_sort` in yml as well:

```
Member:
  default_sort: 'LastEdited DESC'
```

This should overwrite the value from `private static $default_sort`.
Because the hierarchy for the config system is: `Config::inst()->update()` > yml > php private static

besides that using yml is easier in this case, I don't see anything wrong with your DataExtension, perhaps you can't overwrite default_sort with that, I don't know.
If the yml version doesn't work either, than perhaps the list you see does not use the default sort but instead applies its own sorting.
in that case, you need to customise the list and not the member.

Edit: @Tama pointed out in a comment, that the field might have to be part of summary_fields in order to work in the GridField.

Comment: It turned out that because I didn't include "LastEdited" as a summary field the table in Security wouldn't sort on it. Using your method and adding that column worked.